# How to use IR leds that is not working on Pi camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, infrared, noir

For a night vision camera, I bought NoIR Pi camera and [IR leds](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4vZqQ98TdAhXFdd4KHfG1BUMQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.waveshare.com%2Fwiki%2FRPi_Camera_(F)&psig=AOvVaw1-xgKAVvXGtKZrfF2LdWwI&ust=1537373031204426)(Can be attached to both sides of the camera).
But I found that my Pi camera doesn't have metal part on the attaching part. So I cannot use my IR leds with pi camera. Can I use it with pi's gpio? Actually I only need to turn on the leds, so I wonder if I can supply power to leds with raspberry pi or arduino's pins.
Additionally If I connect the leds with jumper cable or something, should I solder it or is it okay just tying it.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your leds to any DC power source, just be sure to limit the current by using a suitable series resistor to avoid destroying your leds. And don't look into them to prevent eye damage, as your eyes will not accomodate to invisible light.

In good approximation:

I = U / R

with:

- I is maximum allowed current trough LED (ampere)
- U is power supply voltage (volt)
- R is value of resistor (ohm)

Or more exact:

https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/219